# Is it possible to limit and track usage in a library that's business logic is running client side?

Tags: javascript, security, authentication

There is a javascript library that runs in the browser. The library executes valuable logic. The access to this logic should be licensed and the usage of it should be tracked.

Is this possible to do? I've seen other services using API-keys to authenticate their client sdk libraries. One of these is sentry.io, which is [using a public key to authenticate the client](https://docs.sentry.io/platforms/javascript/guides/react/). How does/does sentry.io prevent that the public key is stolen and used to send malicious requests to their platform? I have a feeling that it is not secure.

Comment: Once you send code to the browser to execute it, everyone with access to that page can see, reuse and modify it. But logic rarely is valuable by itself - it's the data that the logic runs on. And access to that should be restricted.

Comment: And no, Sentry does not use a public key to authenticate running their client sdk code (which is [open source](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-javascript/tree/master/packages/browser) even). See https://docs.sentry.io/product/sentry-basics/dsn-explainer/#dsn-utilization: "*DSNs are safe to keep public because they only allow submission of new events and related event data; they do not allow read access to any information. While there is a risk of abusing a DSN, where any user can send events to your organization with any information they want, this is a rare occurrence.*"